# `npm start` displays the website right, but when building with `npm build`, a lot of information is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, build

EDIT: Resolved the issue with some help! I just moved the json to the source and imported it directly.

I am making a static portfolio website with react. I developed the website by running a local server with `npm start` and I am done with the website and how it looks. The website works by fetching text from a local json file to populate certain text fields. Since the website looked good with `npm start`, I did `npm build` to build the website to be uploaded and the style and format is all there, but all the text from the json file does not display. I'm not sure what to do here. I am also not sure what information to provide, so here is the package.json and the project structure which may help out.

Here is how the data is fetched.

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foo: 'bar',
      resumeData: {}
    };

    ReactGA.initialize('UA-110570651-1');
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname);

  }

  getResumeData(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'/resumeData.json',
      dataType:'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({resumeData: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err){
        console.log(err);
        alert(err);
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getResumeData();
  }
```

Here is the contents of my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "portfolio_site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is the project structure

```
portfoli_site
│   firebase.json
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│
├───.firebase
│
├───.git
├───build
│   │   404.html
│   │   asset-manifest.json
│   │   favicon.ico
│   │   index.html
│   │   manifest.json
│   │   resumeData.json
│   │
│   ├───css
│   │   │   default.css
│   │   │   fonts.css
│   │   │   layout.css
│   │   │   magnific-popup.css
│   │   │   media-queries.css
│   │   │
│   │   ├───font-awesome
│   │   ├───fontello
│   │   └───fonts
│   │       └─── /* List of Fonts */
│   │
│   ├───images
│   │   ├─── /* List of Images */
│   │   └─── /* Sublist of Images */
│   │
│   ├───js
│   │       init.js
│   │       jquery-1.10.2.min.js
│   │       jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
│   │       jquery.fittext.js
│   │       jquery.flexslider.js
│   │       magnific-popup.js
│   │       modernizr.js
│   │       waypoints.js
│   │
│   └───static
│       ├───css
│       │       main.bab0b925.chunk.css
│       │       main.bab0b925.chunk.css.map
│       │
│       └───js
│               2.5db02833.chunk.js
│               2.5db02833.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt
│               2.5db02833.chunk.js.map
│               main.e8ddd9a1.chunk.js
│               main.e8ddd9a1.chunk.js.map
│               runtime-main.f90b5c1b.js
│               runtime-main.f90b5c1b.js.map
├───public
│   │   404.html
│   │   favicon.ico
│   │   index.html
│   │   manifest.json
│   │   resumeData.json /* WHERE MOST WEBSITE TEXT IS STORED */
│   │
│   ├───css
│   │   │   default.css
│   │   │   fonts.css
│   │   │   layout.css
│   │   │   magnific-popup.css
│   │   │   media-queries.css
│   │   │
│   │   ├───font-awesome
│   │   ├───fontello
│   │   └───fonts
│   ├───images
│   │   ├─── /* List of Images */
│   │   └───portfolio
│   │       └─── /* Sublist of Images */
│   └───js
│           init.js
│           jquery-1.10.2.min.js
│           jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
│           jquery.fittext.js
│           jquery.flexslider.js
│           magnific-popup.js
│           modernizr.js
│           waypoints.js
└───src
    │   App.css
    │   App.js
    │   App.test.js
    │   index.css
    │   index.js
    │   registerServiceWorker.js
    │
    └───Components
        └─── /* List of Components */
```

Comment: how did you fetch the `json` data in your development server, which library did you use?

Comment: Just updated my post to show the code that fetches the data.

Comment: what is the status of the Axios request? is It success? also can include the render function inside your snippet

Comment: when you build your react application, it serve from `build` folder, and there is no json file, so you need to change the `ajax` fetching url and pass the json as well.